# Настройка запуска в PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

Сколько не гуглил, так и не нашел как сделать чтобы работали кнопки справа сверху (обведены). Т.е. чтобы код можно было запускать прямо в pycharm. Скрины настроек тут же.
[image: Кнопки которые не работают]
[image: Run/Debug Configurations]
[image: Project Interpreter]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Вам нужно добавить конфигурацию запуска: сказать PyCharm, какой файл запускать и с какими параметрами. Сделать это можно двумя способами:

1) Простой способ -- кликнуть правой клавишей мыши по области, где вы пишите код и в контекстном меню выбрать run -filename- (первый скриншот)

[image: (скрин 1)]

2) Но также вы можете настроить конфигурации запуска путем открытия настроек конфигурации. Сверху, рядом с кнопкой пуска - Edit configurations -> Add configuration, далее выбираете файл, который хотите запустить (указываете путь до него в поле script path), и нажимаете safe configuration. После чего сможете запустить ваш код прямо в пайшарме (скрины 2-...)

[image: скрин 2]
[image: скрин 3]
[image: скрин 4]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Т.е. не получится настроить кнопку так, чтобы она действовала на открытый в рабочей области файл, а не на файл который запускали с помощью нее ранее и после этого не меняли script path?

Comment: @TheGloomDreamer, чтобы запустить открытый файл, достаточно использовать комбинацию `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`F10`

Comment: @TheGloomDreamer, вы можете настроить несколько конфигураций аналогичным путем. И во время запуска просто выбирать необходимую. Вы также можете запустить сразу несколько файлов в одном проекте, выбрав из списка конфигураций сначала одну, и запустив ее, потом вторую, третью и т.д.